# struggling to get 'deploy to azure button' to work

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I'm struggling to get a Deploy to Azure button to work and hoping someone can help,

my code in the readme.md looks like

```
[![Deploy to Azure](https://aka.ms/deploytoazurebutton)](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/<url encoded link to raw template>
```

when I try the button it takes me to the deploy screen, only I get an error:

"(x) Error parsing template. Please ensure template is valid JSON. Invalid symbol at character position 4. (3 other errors)"

the template validates and works as expected when deployed manually through Deploy a Custom Template,

the raw uri to the template in our tfsgit repo returns the raw template as expected

(the raw uri uses msoft's pattern of [https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/sourceProviders/{{providerName}}/filecontents?repository={{repository}}&path={{path}}&commitOrBranch={{commitOrBranch}}&api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_apis/sourceProviders/%7B%7BproviderName%7D%7D/filecontents?repository=%7B%7Brepository%7D%7D&path=%7B%7Bpath%7D%7D&commitOrBranch=%7B%7BcommitOrBranch%7D%7D&api-version=5.0-preview.1))

I'm guessing might be some kind of authentification issue, I've tried basic auth with username:password@https://...  or maybe it only works with github.com, either way I'm completely stuck

nothing I try seems to work, and azure won't show me the json it's trying to parse,

I was wondering if someone else has had a similar issue and would be able to point me in the right direction here

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you validated your template in the Azure portal -> Deploy from a custom template ? Can be a good start since it says that your template is invalid.

Comment: hi yes, sorry I probably didn't make it clear enough, it validates and deploys fine when entered manually through deploy from custom template

Comment: Are you using Github repos or Azure Devops Repos? Does this issue occurs in Azure devops service(different from azure) or a simple git repo?

Comment: hi, Azure Devops repos and I'm not 100% sure, is it possible to tell if it's in azure services or just a git repo accessible through it?

Comment: [Azure Devops Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops) has some difference from github Repo, what's the result if you post the Readme.md into a private github repo, could the button work?